# Access the same python queue after restarting a process

Tags: python, python-3.x, concurrency, multiprocessing

I have 3 processes - 2 producers that write data in a queue and 1 consumer that reads data from it:

```
queue = Queue()
consumer = ConsumerProcess(queue).start()
producer1 = ProducerAProcess(queue).start()
producer2 = ProducerBProcess(queue).start()
```

I wonder how to get the same queue inside any of these processes if it fails and gets restarted - like get the queue instance by its ID or name, or its file path...

For example, let's say my consumer process was terminated for some reason. Then I want to restart it and keep reading messages from the same queue.

Is there any way to achieve that without utilizing external message brokers like RabbitMQ?

Comment: Not sure I fully understand, but as long as you pass in the same queue every time you restart a process it shoud be fine?

Comment: Well, the problem is that if one of my processes dies the other two will not die automatically. And I want to restart just the failed process, because I don't want to restart them all and therefore lose the contents of the queue

Comment: what do you mean by " lose the contents"? and how do you plan to restart the process?